# How to forward based on port in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

if i have the location to proxy like this:

```
location /proxy{
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
}
```

it will only forward to `localhost:1234`.
Now what i want is something like this:

`/proxy/5544/abcd/1234 -> localhost:5544/abcd/1234
/proxy/5353/xyz/555 -> localhost:5353/xyz/555`

How to achieve this?

**Update**
So what i want to be is a dynamic port mapping following this format:

`/proxy/{port}/{path}`

So here is more of the example of the mapping:

```
localhost/proxy/1234/abcd/xyz -> localhost:1234/abcd/xyz
localhost/proxy/9999/1234/5678 -> localhost:9999/1234/5678
localhost/proxy/8080/sub-path/another-path -> localhost:8080/sub-path/another-path
```

Comment: Add `location /proxy/5544 {}` for each. I can't see why you'd need `/proxy/any` to `:any`. If there was such a wildcard, what would happen if you hit the proxy with `http://127.0.0.1/proxy/80`?

Comment: It might be possible using regular expression matching and variables that come out of the regular expression.

Comment: This is just to be used for cenvinence in development, ofc not for production, but for now somewhat i kinda need this thing to make my development life easier

Answer (score 1):

With the handwriting, there is no test. The general idea is this.

```
location ~ /proxy/(\d+)/(.*)$ {
   set $flag $1;
   set $url $2;
   set $default_port 1234;
   if ($flag ~ 5544) {
      set $default_port 555;
   }

   rewrite ^.*$ /$url break;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$default_port;
}

# curl http://127.0.0.1:555
555
# curl http://127.0.0.1:1234
1234
# curl http://127.0.0.1:80/proxy/5353/index.html
1234
# curl http://127.0.0.1:80/proxy/5544/index.html
555
```

Comment: without even testing it, can tell the result will be wrong

Comment: It is indeed a mistake, haha. But I have revised it again, now he can work :)

Comment: i updated to make it clearer